# PropertiesConfiguration doesn't reload with Symbolic link

Tags: java, symlink, apache-commons-config

Considering the scenario where 'file' is a symbolic link to a real one

```
file -> real_file
```

if I configure `PropertiesConfiguration` (from Apache Commons Config) to open the symbolic link it doens't reload it if I update the real file

```
String filePath = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
PropertiesConfiguration configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration(new File(filePath));
configuration.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
```

Of course, in this case the update date of the symbolic link is unchanged, unlike the real one.

Is there a way to force `PropertiesConfiguration` to follow symbolic link and recognize changes on real file?

Comment: `.getCanonicalPath()` will give you the _real path_ of the file. So in your code example, you are watching the actual file, not the symbolic link. So it does not need to follow the symbolic link in this example. Doesn't this code reload on the changes on the real file?

Comment: Yes, I just discover that the problem is that the pointed file has been replaced by another file, so PropertiecConfiguration is pointing to an not existing file. That's why the reload not works

Comment: Got it. I recommend then writing an answer to your own question, so it can be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.getCanonicalPath()` open the pointed file and not the symblink.
If someone replace the real file with another one `PropertiecConfiguration` is still pointing to an not existing file, so the reload doens't work